# Angular ErrorHandler passed incorrect data

Tags: angular, angular-errorhandler

```
//api.service.ts
public Get(slug: string): Observable<T> {
    return this.http.get(`${environment.apiBaseURL}/${this.endPoint}/${slug}`).pipe(
        map(data => this.serializer.fromJson(data) as T)
    );
}



//global-error-handler.ts
import { Injectable, ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class GlobalErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {
    handleError(error: any) {

        if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
            console.log('type is HttpErrorResponse');
        }
        else
        {
            console.log('type is Error');
        }
    }
}


//app.module.ts
{
    provide: ErrorHandler,
    useClass: GlobalErrorHandler,
}
```

errors from component which have `subscribe` returns `error` as `HttpErrorResponse` (which is the expected type. however, errors from resolvers return `error` as type `Error`.

Custom error types are lost when the error originate from a resolver, and only return the generic `Error` type.

Comment: do you need to handle it here in the service? I have found handling from within the subscription calling the service works well, can highlight how that could work for you if this is an option?

Comment: i handled it from the service to test if the error passed from the service is the expected one, and yep, it is an instance of `HttpErrorResponse` but from the errorHandler it wasn't the same instance, but rather a string.

Comment: i could handle it via subscription, but it kinda repetitive when you can handle it globally. right?

Comment: I think it depends on the application you are making, on a project recently i thought about setting up a service to handle all API error responses but then realised that the although the HTTP error response might be the same in two places based off that i would like to prompt users to do different things so handle it in each place necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

based on the [issue here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/21964#issuecomment-407606052). it is getting a rejected error when an error is thrown from a resolver. so you're loosing the original error. the code below fixes the problem.

```
export class GlobalErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {
    handleError(error: any) {
        error = error.rejection ? error.rejection : error; //this fixes the problem
        if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
            console.log('type is HttpErrorResponse');
        }
        else {
            console.log('type is Error');
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you just call Get without the catchError

```
public Get(slug: string): Observable<T> {
return this.http.get(`${environment.apiBaseURL}/${this.endPoint}/${slug}`)
    .pipe(map(data => this.serializer.fromJson(data) as T))
}
```

and inside your global ErrorHandler you handle all 404/500 Errors

```
@Injectable()
export class GlobalErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {

    handleError(error: any): void {
        if (error.status === 404) {
             console.log('404 Error happened')
             // TODO handle error here (redirect)
        }
    }
}
```